# Flash/ActionScript - Navigating Long Scripts By Locking Selections (Collapse/Expand)?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, bookmarks, pragma

if there's one thing i miss about native programming for Mac OS X using Objective-C and XCode, it's the ability to set #praga marks (essentially bookmarks) to easily navigate thru long scripts via the pull-down menu.

in Flash Authoring CS5 i can can collapse/expand selections of code, but these are removed when the selection is removed - whenever an edit is made.  using collapse/expand selections would be an ideal equivalent to XCode's #pragma marks if it was possible to lock these sections so they don not disappear when the selection disappears, but as far as i know it's not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Flash Builder, or a different ActionScript IDE (FDT, FlashDevelop etc). The Flash IDE wasn't made for more complex coding sessions, that's why CS5 also introduced a better integration with Flash Builder.